# How to find my passphrase?

Tags: web-services, github, ssh, hosting, openshift

I try to do as described here  - [Adding or changing a passphrase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BtcE.jpg) -

```
ssh-keygen -p
# Start the SSH key creation process
# Enter file in which the key is (/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa): [Hit enter]
# Key has comment '/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa'
# Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type new passphrase]
# Enter same passphrase again: [One more time for luck]
# Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
```

but I don't sure about my passphrase  .

I have under - `C:\Users\XXXX\.ssh` the two related files -

**id_rsa.pub -**

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA1VSOsednPUPolm08iQ1lIkaJrThIZ2l4cMUSWbyPaVYRVECrRhbLogHlPRpD4//wU3oskdmckdkdjkdlacQ3hQljEv1yLCA6tK5suOz3qn8Q5JGeD9FuL066yrwD+cOEeRGgPf+1fmx+v4rD8lHwT2BgtIThHtNlQGMhW/K64nZl98lyn3HMrrlL94is70VstVu6Yx9r4mFOi/GYdMZFDwUEWiI2t8aWtLRakKws5tcxgJ57zuLsXMk7d8nayYYLeH1SaP29px98Mo4VOF21maznwqhAgtbDgEEbic3D1Rbdnxj6h/DgolaMOTQ== dsmskdmc@gmail.com
```

**github_rsa.pub -**

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAzsrncWjrpJMl18Tmodm7Jv1MdfY7v4NjDNjt1CfwJ/6z7agtKcn44016EYdPHNl7nM9czxczxczxczczfdfdcxcxcxBqjsKMUQb6p2hV5WGJQJysUSEA3y7s/mDW5QoHBbB0sx4a6a0C5hQi3FIn5seAfiWxTSXQHBWReLgR+EtnvdqVRIhqYgmEQ16CCr9XcVLbdByZlTCWQpD7Sldp6ocgwXlKIY/WQyhaIL8EMfhoMZofTaGXkLfVwww7hIuFDiaR2IOq9PxbZfn3wH+BSbvmpsl+RPVM1zcwEPdse+YceubJDMrSBP0GdQ== dsdsds@dsdsL-THINK
```

Can I restore the passphrase by the above or maybe you have any other suggest ?

**UPDATE:**

Following @IdanArye answer did the follow -

Deleted all previous passwords -

[image]

Add new `SSH key` according to the content in the  `id_rsa.pub` file  -

[image]

[image]

Back to my question , what I have to do now to reveal my `passphrase` ?

Still I get -

```
C:\Users\XXX\Documents\GitHub> ssh-keygen -p
Enter file in which the key is (/c/Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter old passphrase:
Bad passphrase.
```

when I enter the new generated `SSH Key` .

**Update 2:**

again , following @IdanArye updating  - I did the follow in the `Git Shell` -

```
C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\GitHub> ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_rsa):
/c/Users/XXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /c/Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /c/Users/Uriel/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX TTTTTT@UUUUUUU-THINK
C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\GitHub>
```

1) Does what I entered here is consider as my new `passphrase` ?

2) From here , how to generate a new set of public key, private key and `passpharse` ?

Comment: I can only hope you didn't really post your pubkeys here.

Comment: No ... I changed it .. don't worry .

Comment: @florianb What's wrong with sharing the public key online? Isn't the whole point of asymmetric cryptography that you can share the public key? As long as he doesn't post the private key there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @IdanArye you're right i misread that and thought of private keys. Time for end of work.. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. At least - I hope you can't. If you could that would mean the whole passpharse mechanism is broken since anyone who has your private key file will be able to reset or restore your passpharse and use your private key.

True - other people shouldn't get a hold of your private key file in the first place - but that's not always feasible and that's why you use a passpharse as another layer of security.

Instead of trying to restore your passpharse, you should consider creating a new RSA key. If you only use it for Github you can just update your new public key at https://github.com/settings/ssh. If you use it with other sites you should also update it there - if you forgot your passpharse chances are you don't use your RSA key that often and don't have your public key registered in too many places...

And next time - remember your passpharse!

## Update(answering the question's update):

There is no point in removing the old public key from GitHub if you are just going to re-add **the same** public key.

In order to use that public key you need the private key associated with it. In order to use a private key you need the passpharse it's encrypted in it. If you forgot that passpharse, you can't use that private key which means you can't decrypt messages encrypted with that public key or encrypt messages that'll be decrypted with that public key, so there is no point in registering that public key in GitHub.

That public key is lost for you. Unless you somehow recall the passpharse - you need a new set of public key, private key and passpharse.

The `-p` flag of `ssh-keygen` is used for changing the passpharse, and as you have witnessed you need the old passpharse to do so. If you call `ssh-keygen` without the `-p` flag you will be able to create a new key, with a new passpharse. This new key is the one you need to register on GitHub(and any other site that require it for SSH access)

## Update2(answering the question's update2):

1. Yes, what you have entered there is your new passpharse.
2. You already did! Notice this part in your interactive shell session log:

   ```
   /c/Users/XXXXXX/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
   Overwrite (y/n)? y
   ```

   This means you have overwritten the old `id_rsa` file and a new one is created. This new `id_rsa` file is your new private key, encrypted with your new passpharse. `ssh-keygen` has also overwritten the matching `id_rsa.pub` file with your new public key. You can tell that by looking at the output lines:

   ```
   Your identification has been saved in /c/Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_rsa.
   Your public key has been saved in /c/Users/XXXX/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
   ```

   `identification` here means the private key encrypted with the passpharse.

Comment: can you take a look on my UPDATE please  ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an answer to your update.

Comment: Thanks a lot , can you take a look on my new update (update 2) please ?